# C# Cast / Unbox using variable Types

Tags: c#, unboxing

Is there a way to unbox/cast using variable types like

```
var varType = typeof(int);
var variable = 5;
return (varType)variable;
```

Comment: you must include more information.

Comment: Boxing happens when you store a value type in an object-type.  `(object)5` is a boxed value.  `(object)(new Spork())` is not, as `Spork` is already the mightiest object.

Comment: @Amy technically `Spork` could be a struct, in which case the second example you provided is still boxing.

Comment: @DanielCrha in my example, `Spork` is a class, not a value type.

Comment: @Amy right, just thought I'd point that out. You did specify that it is an object in a very cheeky way, but I just wanted to make it clear to anyone looking at this question that seeing `new` doesn't mean no boxing occurs.

Comment: @DanielCrha Gotcha.  We're on the same page.  No, you're right, I said it was an object, but I didn't use the word "class".  You made an important distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue in the premise of your question. C# is a statically typed language, and the type of each variable must be known at compile time. There is no getting around this, so you either have to specify the type of your object, or use `dynamic` as a type (*please* don't unless you're doing interop or something similar).

In your example, the type of `varType` is `Type`. The type of `variable` is `int`. But what is then the return type of this function if what you proposed existed in C#? Since `varType` could hold any type, the return type of this function would only be known at run-time, which is not possible in a statically typed language.

Perhaps if you provided a more concrete example of where you think you need to use something like this, there might be a better way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You question requires a little more info to answer, so I'm going to add some.  Consider that you have a function like

```
int GetSomeInt () {
    var i = (object)5;     //at this point, i is a boxed int
    return (int)i;         //we are unboxing I back into an int and returning it
}
```

The other thing you could do is:

```
object GetBoxedInt () {
    var i = 5;
    return (object)i;        //here we are returning boxed int back to the caller
}
```

What you can't do is return a boxed anything back to a caller as anything other than an `object`; as far as I know there's no way to express a type that conceptually might be:

```
Boxed<T> where T: struct
```

And,

- Boxing is always "taking a value type instance and converting to be an `object`"
- Unboxing is "taking a previously boxed value type instance and converting it back to be *the exactly same type* as it was when it started its life"

Oh... You put more words in your question.  My answer predates your first line of code: `var varType = typeof(int);`  I had assumed that `varType` was a type name (like `object` or `int` or `MyClass`).  However, my answer still mostly holds - with the exception that the answer to your exact question (after editing) is `*No*`